# Upload file to sharepoint using custom field type

Tags: file-upload, custom-field-types

I am rendering the fields of a content type in my page.
The name field is rendered, and is a Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FileField control.
I select a file in this field, and I post the page.

How can I get the posted file of the FileField control in order to save it to SharePoint?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this question? If yes, could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same as the Stack Overflow question [Can a Content Type have a site column of type file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311690/sharepoint-can-a-content-type-have-a-site-column-of-type-file) The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311690/sharepoint-can-a-content-type-have-a-site-column-of-type-file/1313156#1313156) is you can't do this:

> a content type either represents a
>   file or it doesn't. You can't have a
>   file as metadata to a content type
>   that does not derive from document.